# How get all log events in amazon via loop?

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb, amazon-cloudwatchlogs

Every amazon API has it's own token which you have to set to next request. But with aws log api I got infinity loop:

```
public class Some {
    public static void main (String[] args) {
        final GetLogEventsRequest request = new GetLogEventsRequest()
                .withLogGroupName("myGroup")
                .withLogStreamName("myStrean");
        final AWSLogs awsLogs = AWSLogsClientBuilder.defaultClient();
        Collection<OutputLogEvent> result = new ArrayList<>();

        GetLogEventsResult response = null;
        do {
            response = awsLogs.getLogEvents(request);
            result.addAll(response.getEvents());
            request.withNextToken(response.getNextBackwardToken());
        } while (response.getNextBackwardToken() != null);
    }
}
```

From documentation:

> nextBackwardToken
>
> The token for the next set of items in the backward direction. The token expires after 24 hours. This token will never be null. If you have reached the end of the stream, it will return the same token you passed in.

So it can not be null like [LastEvaluatedKey](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/APIReference/API_Scan.html#API_Scan_ResponseSyntax) when you [scan](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/ScanJavaDocumentAPI.html) dynamodb:

```
Map<String, AttributeValue> lastKeyEvaluated = null;
do {
    ScanRequest scanRequest = new ScanRequest()
        .withTableName("ProductCatalog")
        .withLimit(10)
        .withExclusiveStartKey(lastKeyEvaluated);

    ScanResult result = client.scan(scanRequest);
    for (Map<String, AttributeValue> item : result.getItems()){
        printItem(item);
    }
    lastKeyEvaluated = result.getLastEvaluatedKey();
} while (lastKeyEvaluated != null);
```

So and what I should pass to `request.withNextToken` if we speak about log api??? And if `nextBackwardToken` (and `nextForwardToken` too) can not be null - how to detect that I receive the last response from amazon???

Comment: You need to see if the token's are the same; if they are then you're at the end of the stream.

Comment: The same - you mean tokens from previous and next responses right?

Comment: Yes. If they're the same, then you're at the end of the stream.

Answer (score 0):

The documentation which you've cited is quite straightforward. I think you need something like this:

```
    final AWSLogs awsLogs = AWSLogsClientBuilder.defaultClient();
    Collection<OutputLogEvent> result = new ArrayList<>();

    String nextToken = null;
    GetLogEventsResult response;
    do {
        GetLogEventsRequest request = new GetLogEventsRequest()
                .withLogGroupName("myGroup")
                .withLogStreamName("myStrean");
        if (nextToken != null) request = request.withNextToken(nextToken);

        response = awsLogs.getLogEvents(request);
        result.addAll(response.getEvents());

        // check if token is the same
        if (response.getNextForwardToken().equals(nextToken)) break;
        // save new token
        nextToken = response.getNextForwardToken();
    } while (true);
```

So, you simply need to create request each time with the new token, until it becomes equals to the old one.